# backgroundImage is not finding my url path

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to apply a backgroundImage but it's not finding my local path url.

I try:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
const loginWrapperStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
image: {
        backgroundImage: 'url(../../../public/assets/regbackground.jpg)',
}}))
```

If i use the import as a test to find the assets folder, they say this is the correct path:

[image]

This is the exactly name/format of the image:

[image]

What i'm doing wrong?
My image is not rendering.

Comment: Was my answer useful for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import image from '../../../public/assets/regbackground.jpg'
const loginWrapperStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
image: {
        backgroundImage: `url(${image})`,
}}))
```